# Add to Magento admin-side global search

Tags: magento

How can I add a database field to the Magento global search? I want to create a custom "business name" field in customers and then have it searchable with that global search bar on the administrative panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found it in `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Search_Customer`. This class has a method `load()` that you can modify to return additional search results and changed subtext. Oddly enough, Magento actually has you load *all* possible search resutls for a search and then limits them, but regardless here's the code to add search on a custom field:

Old Code:

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->joinAttribute('company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute'=>'firstname', 'like'=>$this->getQuery().'%'),
            array('attribute'=>'lastname', 'like'=>$this->getQuery().'%'),
            array('attribute'=>'company', 'like'=>$this->getQuery().'%'),
        ))
        ->setPage(1, 10)
        ->load();
```

I created a class in the local space to override this function and added the following:

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->joinAttribute('company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('company_name', 'customer/company_name', 'entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
            array('attribute'=>'firstname', 'like'=>$this->getQuery().'%'),
            array('attribute'=>'lastname', 'like'=>$this->getQuery().'%'),
            array('attribute'=>'company', 'like'=>$this->getQuery().'%'),
            array('attribute'=>'company_name', 'like'=>$this->getQuery().'%'),
        ))
        ->setPage(1, 10)
        ->load();
```

Now I can use the global search for my custom attribute! Hopefully that will help someone else.

Thanks,
Joe